# Catching 401 error when a googleapiclient build fails?

Tags: google-api-client, google-api-python-client

I am currently trying to catch an edge case when a user removes my app as a third party app without having us aware of the event. I currently don't know of any way that google would let me know if a token has been revoked until I get a `google.auth.exceptions.RefreshError: ('invalid_grant: Token has been expired or revoked.', '{\n  "error": "invalid_grant",\n  "error_description": "Token has been expired or revoked."\n}')`

I've tried manually 'pinging' the google client before I auth the user, but it seems a bit slower than just catching and handling the error when it occurs. I've also tried directly importing the auth error. `import google.auth.exceptions.RefreshError as AuthError`

Retrieving credentials:

```py
storage = Storage(GCalUser, 'gcal_user', request.user, 'credentials')
user_credentials = storage.get()
```

Actual call:

```py
try:
    calendar_service = googleapiclient.discovery.build('calendar', 'v3', credentials=user_credentials)
    print("Error 2: " + str(calendar_service))
except calendar_service:
    pass
```

Looking for way to direct the user to a different page if there is an error on auth. Currently it just fails with the `google.auth.exceptions.RefreshError: ('invalid_grant: Token has been expired or revoked.', '{\n  "error": "invalid_grant",\n  "error_description": "Token has been expired or revoked."\n}')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed with explicitly fully importing the error from the module `from google.auth.exceptions import RefreshError`. As it turns out, the error wasn't thrown on building with the user credentials but was thrown on executing using the api.

```py
try:
    calendar_list = calendar_service.calendarList().list(pageToken=page_token, minAccessRole="writer").execute()
except RefreshError:
    print("Hello debugging!")
```